# Cannot get number to increment above 10

Tags: php, mysql

Ok, so a strange one that I've never seen before. The bit of script you are about to see gets a value from a table, explodes it and then increments the number stored in the array, so I can then use it to create a unique product code. However, the number refuses to increment once it hits 10. Here is the script:

```
$query = $this->mysqli_link->query("SELECT custom_id FROM sjs_custom_orders ORDER BY custom_id DESC LIMIT 1")->fetch_array();
$custom_id_old = $query['custom_id'];
$custom_id_new_split = explode("/", $custom_id_old);
$custom_id = $custom_id_new_split[2] + 1;
$custom_id_new = "SJS/CUSTOM/" . $custom_id;
```

The table itself has the custom_id column set as a varchar(100).

Any help appreciated.

Comment: varchar there's the problem. use `int`

Comment: Thing is though, the custom_id is a mixture of letters and numbers

Comment: the ID's are not PK's, they need to be created on client.

Comment: The text in the id seems pretty redundant here: Your table name is `sjs_custom_orders` and your ids start with `SJS/CUSTOM/`. Just use `int`s.

Comment: you can't do math with text

Comment: what do you mean when : *Cannot get number to increment above 10*? echo? mysql error? php error? wrong value?

Comment: @Fred-ii- - I'm not trying to do math with text. I'm incrementing the number independently of the text, hence the reason why I exploded custom_id and ran the +1 on the number only which will always be key 2 in the array.

Comment: @Alex: No errors are being returned, however when I put new values into the database using this script, the number never goes above 10

Comment: @jeroen: the text is required in the ID

Comment: did you try to `echo $custom_id_new;`?

Comment: it may help others if you were to post your db schema for this, seeing the answer below hasn't been accepted, or you're still trying to make it work.

Comment: *"however when I put new values into the database using this script, the number never goes above 10"* - now that's unclear. You doing an INSERT INTO or just straight hard coded in db? this makes your question even more unclear.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'm using an INSERT TO script, however the issue occurs BEFORE I insert the data into the DB.

Comment: @Alex yeah I did that, and it echoed nothing, got the answer below working now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in your query.

`ORDER BY custom_id DESC`

Because the (unfortunately named) `custom_id` column is *character* type, this value:

```
SJS/CUSTOM/9
```

will sort before (in descending order) this value:

```
SJS/CUSTOM/10
```

because the comparison is character to character. The `'9'` is greater than `'1'`. As humans, we may perceive *ten* to be greater than *nine*. But MySQL is just comparing character to character. If we added a `'0'` character before the `'9'`, so the database was comparing `'09'` to `'10'`, we'd be closer to getting  the result we expect.

---

If the value of `custom_id` always contains two forward slashes, and you want the numeric value after the last forward slash, you can parse that out with a SQL expression

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX(custom_id,'/',-1)+0
```

(Add a zero converts the string to numeric value. MySQL is wonky the way it does that, it won't throw an error, it converts the leading portion, as much as it can, into a numeric.

If there's always two slashes, you can get the part before that second slash with an expression as well:

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX(custom_id,'/',2)
```

To get the "maximum" value, you could do this...

```
ORDER
   BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(custom_id,'/',2) DESC
    , SUBSTRING_INDEX(custom_id,'/',-1)+0 DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

NOTE: This "works" as long as `custom_id` *always* contains two forward slashes. If there's any values of `custom_id` that aren't like that, the behavior of these expressions is well defined, but unlikely to return the result you want.

---

MySQL will not be able to make effective use of an index to satisfy this query; those expressions will need to be evaluated for *every* row in the table. If you're stuck with this unfortunate design, then you're stuck with it. We'd prefer to see the results from these expressions stored separately, in two separate columns.

Comment: ok spencer, will give that a go thank you

Comment: that's working, thanks for the help, will try and explore different ways of getting the code to work in the future without having to do inefficient queries :) thanks again